# Replacing object in Google Cloud Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-cdn

I am trying to replace an object(video) in google cloud bucket after doing certain operations over it giving it the same name. Giving it same name because it's already shared to multiple users. While doing an operation over it and while replacing it, some chunks of video becomes temporarily unavailable for people who are playing that video at that time and they face issue for a few seconds because of this.

So I have a question that whether its possible to replace the object in-place without affecting the existing version loaded in some places. Also to add I have CDN above this bucket too. Can object versioning on this bucket help me here? I want to keep the name same so that I dont have to send this link again to everyone

Comment: I fear that you can't solve that easily...

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar situation.  When I called support, they had me name the new file EXACTLY the same as the original file.  Delete the original file from your bucket.  Upload the new file that has the exact same name, and the URL will be the same as the original URL.